# Simple factory design in C# calling factory from another factory?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, factory

I need to create an object with a simple factory in C#, that object has a dependency object that is also created using another simple factory.

Is it a good design principle to call a simple factory from another simple factory? I think I might be doing something strange.

I have the following:

```
interface IObjecAtImplement {
    void task();
}

interface IObjecBtImplement {
    void taskFoo();
    void anotherTaskFoo();
}

public static class ObjectAFactory {

    public static IObjecAtImplement Get(string objecttype) {
        IObjectBImplement objectB = ObjectBFactory.Get(objecttype);
        switch (objecttype)
        case "A";
            return ObjectAFirstImplementacion(objectB);
        case "B";
            return ObjectASecondImplementacion(objectB);
    }
}

public static class ObjectBFactory {
    public static IObjecBtImplement Get(string objecttype) {    
        switch (objecttype)    
        case "A";
            return new ObjectBFirstImplementacion();
        case "B";
            return new ObjectBSecondImplementacion();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a good idea at all? is there any other way of solving it? (The code brackets are not well written, it's just an example)

Comment: Why using static class for the factories? Define interfaces for the factories too and pass them via constructor where needed

Comment: Thanks, that a good point I will do that. But my question is: is it a good idea to call one factory from another factory? is that "normal"? thanks

Comment: Why not? The only anti-pattern here is the strong dependency with your static classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to combine two patterns in one: [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). Factories are responsible for creation of an object, while injecting dependencies is usually a department of IoC containers.

To preserve clear responsibilities of your classes, I would suggest looking into using one of many [IoC containers in .NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx).